# How are B Tree nodes typically represented?

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree, b-tree

I've been doing some brushing up on my B-Tree and 2-3-4 tree (B tree with order 4), and I'm attempting to implement this in C#.  My question to you is, given that a B-Tree node can contains N-1 number of items and N subtrees, what is the typical representation for one of these nodes? Is it an array, series of linked-lists, or something I've not considered?

Comment: so in the case where N is 2 there can be _one_ subtree? that's usually called a list and not a tree :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 2-3-4 tree, it does not really matter. For large orders, you'd use a sorted array and binary search. For variable-size keys like Strings, a trie might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to combine sub-trees and items. You will need **2** arrays or List<>'s.

If your order is fixed i would use 2 arrays. Otherwise, a `List<ItemClass>` and a `List<SubTree>`

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an interesting article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379572%28VS.80%29.aspx) about writing a binary search tree in C#. Not exactly the same as a b-tree but you may find it useful. The author in this case uses a generic Collection base class:

```
public class Node<T>
{
   private T data;
   private NodeList<T> neighbors = null;
   ...
}

public class NodeList<T> : Collection<Node<T>> { ... }
```

Comment: Yes, that's why I have in the body of my post (2nd sentence), "Not exactly the same as a b-tree, but you may find it useful."  The idea being that the base type for the collection is simply Collection<T>, not a LinkedList or Array like the OP mentioned.